# Coordinate format query (to create shapefile in ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, shapefile

I am trying to create a shapefile for houses in a particular region (using WGS84).

I have GPS data for the houses but when I attempt to create the shape file I end up with just two dots, rather than the several thousand there should be.  I think the coordinates may be in the wrong format or something similar.  Below is the header for the GPS CSV file:

> "HOUSENO","LAT","LNG"
> "030001",-13.8687844973, 33.77119498
> "030002",-13.8688912878, 33.7711557065
> "030003",-13.8691931635, 33.7705599931
> "030004",-13.8691981756, 33.7705450562

What coordinate format does this looks like and what should it be to make valid shapefiles?

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe your workflow for creating the shape? Make XY Event Layer?

Comment: (I get four points in Malawi with your sample using QGIS and WGS84 EPSG:4326)

Comment: There are an infinite number of potential CSV "formats" so the entire idea of a *known format* for ASCII output is pretty much a lost cause.  Instead, focus on actually processing the data, which appears to have a div 10 unique ID, with a modulus-10 sequence before lat and lon. Processing this sort of data is pretty basic, once you get used to the idea of caching previous rows until the ID changes, then working with the last N rows (you have to handle the special cases of an empty cache on start, and a full cache at the end of input).

Comment: Once you have the Python to call a fuction with a list of coordinate pairs, you can start the GIS component, based on ArcPy DA InsertCursor.